# Suitescript 1.0 Save value in multiselect field using setFieldValues

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript1.0

I have a legacy SuiteScript 1.0 script and I want to load a customer record and check whether a specific multiselect field has any selected values.  If no values are selected, I want to add a default value.

I can load the record and verify if the field contains a value.  I can add value(s) to multiselect fields in the customer record but NOT for the "leadsource" field which produces the error:

```
"Please enter value(s) for: Leadsource".
```

There seems to be something special about the "leadsource" field which requires special handling.  Any ideas?

```
function postRESTlet(dataIn) {

  var record = nlapiLoadRecord('customer', 17417);
  var values = new Array();
  var leadsource = record.getFieldValues('leadsource');

  if(leadsource === null) {  
    values[0] = '-2';
    record.setFieldValues('leadsource', values);
  }

  nsid = nlapiSubmitRecord(record); 
  return nsid;

}
```

Comment: it's indeed SuiteScript 1.0, please disregard this comment

Comment: Are you able to set the value '-2' manually via the web interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the leadsource field is supposed to be an array of strings only in case there are multiple values. Otherwise it's just sting. So just use `-2`, like:

```
function postRESTlet(dataIn) {
  var record = nlapiLoadRecord('customer', 17417);
  var values = new Array();
  var leadsource = record.getFieldValues('leadsource');

  if(leadsource === null) {
    values = '-2';
    record.setFieldValues('leadsource', values);
  }

  nsid = nlapiSubmitRecord(record);
  return nsid;
}
```

This will get rid of the error

> "Please enter value(s) for: Leadsource"

but you may have others, e.g.

> Please enter value(s) for: Invoice Email

which is out of scope of this question